# Event based Transaction Logging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, events, async-await

I wanted to write transaction logs at a central localtion (using log4net). But i dont want me classes to call log4net.info("message") every where in the code.

Rather I am looking for events. Each method can raise logging events and my TransactionHandler class handles all those events. How can I do this? Any code example will be helpful.

Comment: Give a try to PostSharp or other aspect orienting library

Comment: Another option if you're not too deep already is the decorator pattern. Simpleinjector makes it very easy to implement and also supports resolution by type constraints. [SimpleInjector docs](http://simpleinjector.readthedocs.io/en/latest/aop.html)

Comment: Is you question "How to log asynchronously", or is it "how to log automatically in declaration-like style"?